# Corona maps and direction

Tags: maps, coronasdk, direction

i'm using corona for an app i'm making.For the contact page, i wanted to add directions from where you are to where the place is. I was wondering how i could get to do that. Mapview doesnt seem to have those options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native.newMapView() does not appear to support directions, however you can use URL scheme's to call out to the native map app and use that to provide the directions.   See this blog post for more info:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/18/reintroducing-google-maps/